# How To use PI Icon on a button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

Hello I am creating a calculator in WPF an I cannot find a font that actually has a PI icon. Can someone please tell me how to have a PI Icon on a button?

Comment: Nearly every font that comes pre-installed on Windows has a Pi character.

Comment: ok font awesome doens't, mahapps doesnt, can you pleae tell me one that does?

Comment: What about e.g. Arial or Calibri? It's a native WPF app, shouldn't it respect the system defaults anyway?

Comment: Thank you I was able to google that, I didn't know this.

Comment: `<Button Content="" />`

Comment: So how you get the PI symbol to be typed is Alt 2-2-7. I didn't know this.

Comment: Do you really want a text character?  A path will scale to the parent control. I can easily give you this for pi if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unicode characters. For PI use `Content="&#960;"`:

```
<Button Content="&#960;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

Comment: I found the unicode (HTML Entity (decimal)) for PI on this site [PI Unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03c0/index.htm)